# Calling an instance method using autowired bean

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have three classes (Class **A**, Class **B**, Class **C**) in my application.

I'm a spring beginner. Trying to inject a bean of Class **B** to use in Class **A** using `@Autowired` annotation. I want to make use of the Singleton behaviour of spring beans so that there will be only instance of Class **B** no matter how many times it is invoked from Class **A**.

There's a method in Class **B** which I want to call from Class **A** using this bean of Class **B**. How can I do that?

I know how to implement a singleton class in Java and then get the one and only instance to call it's methods but not sure how to do that using spring singleton beans.

Comment: Spring singleton != Java singleton

Comment: Show what you have done.  Include the Spring config files (if you use XML config) or the Java config.

Answer (score 2):

Spring singleton is defined as "per container per bean"

If you want singleton per spring container below is what needs to be done in your bean definition

```
<bean id="myBean" class="MyBean"/>
```

If you want the singleton per entire application and not per container, then I believe the only way you can do that is implement a Singleton pattern have a private constructor, access/retrieve it from its static method like getInstance. What you can do is allow spring to call a method that can in turn return an object

```
<bean id="myBean" class="MyBean" factory-method="getInstance"></bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Every class marked as `@Component`, `@Service`, `@Repository` etc. is singleton, but only inside a spring container. So it better to say they are in [single scope](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html).

```
@Component
public class MyBean {
    [...]
}
```

The other option to define a bean in singleton scope is to mark a method as `@Bean`. The return type will be cached so you will use always the same instance if you are calling this method:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    [...]

    @Bean
    @Scope("singleton")
    public MyOtherBean myOtherBean() { // singleton factory method
        return [...];
    }

}
```

But `@Bean` should be used in `@Configuration`-beans only. Inside a `@Service` bean you can just inject the required bean (`@Autowired`).